# Get an id then put it into a href

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, get, href

I'm a bit new to this so sorry if this has been covered already but i'm going around in circles searching.

I've had a look around learn t how to edit htaccess and use the get function, I then even found a plugin called redirection that did similar.

What I would like to do is if I have a URL http://example.com/file.php?id=blue

is to grab the id which is "blue"

then in a href link dynamically add it to the end of another url

```
 <a href="http://www.domain.com/file.php?id=blue">Link Example</a>
```

If someone could help show me or point me in the right direction on how to get the id blue and add it into a href that would be great.

Many Thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to use $_GET.  People might be dicks about it here - but I had a hard time when I was first learning to program too.  You'll get it, don't worry.

This is how get works (at least, all you need to know about how it works):

if you have the file **index.php**
if you add a query string to the end of it like **index.php?id=1**
   You can access id=1 by doing the following in your code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Similarly if the query string contains the following **index.php?id=1&page=5&par=3&club=putter&upnext=tigerwoods**

On the left hand of the equal sign is the Key(id, page, par, club, upnext) and on the right side their value(1,5,3,putter,tigerwoods)

One thing to remember is that when retrieving numbers from the query string they will always be of the string type, so you cant do something like

```
if ( $_GET['page'] === 5 )
```

you'll have to do

```
if ( $_GET['page'] == 5 )
```

and to echo it into a link:

```
$club = $_GET['club'];



 if ( $club == 'NRA' ) {
         echo "<a href='file.php?page=$club' title="lets buy some guns!">Gun Show</a>";
         echo 'Buy tickets to my gunshow ^^';
   }
```

Hope this helps!

You can also do things like set your website up so that it has one template and use the $_GET parameter to determine which files to include into the content sections of the site via a switch command.  I do this, but not across my whole site.  For my user control panel, I do this to simply include only the file necessary (change email, update password, delete account, update profile, etc)

Cah'piche?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$_GET` parameter.

<sub>YAY!!</sub>